# index.getAll() on indexedDB returns empty array

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

IndexedDB noob here...

```
const queueStore = db.createObjectStore("queue", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
queueStore.createIndex("HasBeenSent", ["sent"], { unique: false });
```

I am queuing data, awaiting an upload to a server at a later time, so for now the "sent" value is zero for each record; I'll update the record to reflect "sent" equals 1 later.

When I try to get all the records where the value of "sent" is zero, I get an empty result, using

```
request = db.transaction('queue').objectStore('queue').index('HasBeenSent').getAll(0);
```

If I remove the zero and just have empty brackets, I get all the rows in the store, but if I include any value in the brackets (0, 1, -1, etc) every time I get empty results, even if I definitely have stored records with those values.

(Have I messed something up in the configuration?)

How do I query the store to return all rows where "sent" equals zero??

Comment: Isn't it an async operation? Don't you need `await db.transaction` or something? (I've never used IndexedDb, it's just a guess)

Comment: What are the actual values and types of values of the sent property as stored in the data? Can you open up devtools and inspect the sent property? Are you sure you are connecting to a database that has the data? Can you also try IDBKeyRange.only(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through various sources that getAll() is ok on small datasets, but it can be slow and hungry on large datasets, so I decided to use cursors which should perform better on both large and small datasets.  But, I ran into the same issue with empty results.

What didn't work:

```
const request = db.transaction('queue').objectStore('queue').index('sent').openCursor(0);
```

nor

```
const request = db.transaction('queue').objectStore('queue').index('sent').openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(0));
```

What DID work

```
const keyrange = IDBKeyRange.only(0);
const request = db.transaction('queue').objectStore('queue').index('sent').openCursor(keyrange);
```

I imagine (but never tested) that using getAll(), you'd need to do something similar by defining the keyrange first, then including that in the getAll() request, like

```
const keyrange = IDBKeyRange.only(0);
const request = db.transaction('queue').objectStore('queue').index('sent').getAll(keyrange);
```